# React conditional render based on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm just wondering what is the most efficient/elegant way to do this?

I have a component and it will set the color based on percent. Currently, the function is not working.

```
const App = () => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(51);
  const [color, setColor] = useState("");

  const updateColor = color => {
    if (progress >= 35) {
      setColor("#E75143");
    } else if (progress < 36 && progress > 60) {
      setColor("#FFBF00");
    } else if (progress < 61) {
      setColor("#13D1C5");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Progress
        /* strokeColor={updateColor(color)} */ strokeColor={color}
        percent={progress}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Edit quizzical-tree-ufsyn]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we talking about a more "elegant" solution, I would suggest something like this with a colors config, as it's more "maintainable":

```
// This object can be used across all applications.
const COLORS = {
  OPTION1: {
    color: 'FFBF00',
    interval: [0, 34]
  },
  OPTION2: {
    color: '#E75143',
    interval: [35, 60]
  },
  OPTION3: {
    color: '#13D1C5',
    interval: [60, 100]
  }
};

const getOptionByProgress = progress => {
  return Object.values(COLORS).find(({ interval }) => {
    const [min, max] = interval;
    return min <= progress && progress <= max;
  });
};

const App = () => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(51);
  return (
    <Progress
      strokeColor={getOptionByProgress(progress).color}
      percent={progress}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't need a state for color. Use a method to retrieve the color.

```
const App = () => {
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(59);

  const updateColor = () => {
    if (progress >= 35 && progress < 60) {
      return "#E75143"
    } else if (progress < 35 ) {
      return "#FFBF00"
    } else if (progress >= 60) {
      return "#13D1C5";
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Progress
        /* strokeColor={updateColor(color)} */ strokeColor={updateColor()}
        percent={progress}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an effect that sets the `color` with `progress` as dependency:

```
useEffect(() => {
  setColor(progress >= 35 ? '#E75143' : '#13D1C5')
}, [progress])
```

Any time the `progress` state changes the effect is fired, setting `color`.

Comment: Is there a shorter way to write the if statement?

Comment: You could do it with a switch statement @Freddy.

Comment: The second if statement could never be true, so I removed it and simplified the if statement. You could use `switch` like @Konstantin said, but that wouldn't make it shorter per se.

Comment: I don't think that there is really a shorter way of writing this if. ( You can probably go for oneliner, but it will be totally not readable. ) I would suggest writing some utils function that will take progress and return color hash.
```const getColorByProgress = progress => if (progress >= 35) {
    return "#E75143";
  } else if (progress < 36 && progress > 60) {
    return "#FFBF00";
  } else if (progress < 61) {
    return "#13D1C5";
  }```
And then just import this function in your component so the code will be:
```useEffect(() => getColorByProgress(progress), [progress])```